# how to test servlet result JSON string with http GET request?

Tags: json

I have a bean that generates JSON string, how can I test run the result -- retrievable through a URL via GET HTTP request by opening it in my browser -- to check whether the url is working correctly is by opening it up in the browser

I have mapped the bean in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>queryreturn</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.queryData.Return.QueryReturn</servlet-class>    
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>queryreturn</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/queryreturn</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the bean, how do I test it to see the JSON string?

```
package com.queryData.Return;
//Import required java libraries
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.queryData.main.Main;
// Extend HttpServlet class
public class QueryReturn extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void init() throws ServletException
      {
          // Do required initialization
      }
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException
      {
          Main m = new Main();
          List<JSONObject> jObj = m.getJsonObject();
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for(int i =0 ; i < jObj.size(); i++) 
          {
             sb.append(jObj.get(i).toString());
          }         
          String responseStr = "{\"data\":[" + sb + "]}";

          // Set response content type
          response.setContentType("application/json");
          // Actual logic goes here.
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println(responseStr);

      }
      public void destroy()
      {
          // do nothing.
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running tomcat in the default port (8080) you should be able to access the servlet on http://localhost:8080/queryreturn.

A well known application to make HTTP requests is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can use that to test the servlet response. If you are a linux user you can also use curl.

Comment: Tomcat is running HTTP/1.1 at 8080

Comment: when I run the servlet from Eclipse it first wants to download the file, so I allow it to download, then it asks what to view it with, and I select IE, then the URL is [link]C:\Users\pc\Downloads\queryreturn.json[link] How can I run it with the URL you provided above ?

Comment: You just need to put that url on your browser, or, even better, use postman to make the request. Choose GET request and then paste that url in the proper field. Here there is a tutorial of how to make requests using postman [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) .

Comment: it does not work in the browser or in the Eclipse browser

Comment: when I run it from Eclipse -- Run on Server (tomcat server at localhost) -- it:
1.  dialog pop up File Download NAME queryreturn.json with the option to FIND SAVE CANCEL

2. I click SAVE then it saves to drive
3. Then it asks what to open it with, I select Internet Explorer
4. Then it finally displays the JSON string correctly

Comment: As far as I can see, is a simple GET request, so it should work on your browser by just writing the url an hiting enter. You should check what is the http response code to find out where the problem is coming from. I strongly recommend you to not use eclipse browser to test your servlet. Give postman a try!.

Comment: postman returns an 404 error

'    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /queryreturn</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>/queryreturn</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.9</h3>
    </body>

'

Comment: Wait... are you using eclipse to launch tomcat?.Make sure that the server is running when you are trying to make the request. 404 means that the servlet cannot be reached.

Comment: Also you should check the tomcat logs to see if the servlet was properly deployed.

Comment: yes the server is running from viewing in the Servers tab that it is Started, Synchronized  there is an error but I am not sure it is related, with "Unhandled even loop exeception"